# SSRS Showing a textbox when a second page is displayed

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am creating an Invoice in SSRS and I need to be able to show a textbox with "Balance Brought Forward" in if the amount of lines in the invoice goes over one page limit. So if i restrict the page to 5 lines and there is 10 - 15 lines which will equate to 2 or 3 pages, I need to be able to show this value from the previous pages total on invoice, but only on the 2nd and 3rd pages not on the 1st page. I am able to code in VB if that is the best way to do it, I am just really stuck on how I would achieve this.

Should this be done before generating the report in SQL or can it be achieved in the report it's self?

Comment: Think it would be best done in SQL if you already know that you are going to restrict it to max 5 lines per page. Don't think SSRS is very good at what you want to achieve..

Answer (score 0):

Can you put that in a header row and hide it on page 1?  Or add the textbox and toggle the hidden property based on the number of rows returned.

IIf ((calculate # rows) > 5, False, True)